# Spring Cloud Config Server in 'native' mode doesn't quite work in Windows environment

Tags: windows, spring-cloud

Got what I needed to work on OSX. On Windows, things went a little south.

I am using 'native' mode to share a local properties file across multiple services (spring cloud client). I have:

```
-Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=C:/Development/SVN/WSR_20150711/wsr-config/config/
```

And `C:\Development\SVN\WSR_20150711\wsr-config\config\wsr\wsr-dev.properties` exists. But looks like spring cloud config server is not picking up this file when I specify the resource via URI `/wsr/dev/wsr` -- which works in OSX and Linux.

I did a little digging around and found that there might be some issue with the code at `NativeEnvironmentRepository`, line 135 - 158:

```
            if (normal.startsWith("file:")) {
                normal = new File(normal.substring("file:".length()))
                        .getAbsolutePath();
            }
            for (String pattern : StringUtils
                    .commaDelimitedListToStringArray(getLocations(searchLocations,
                            result.getLabel()))) {
                if (!pattern.contains(":")) {
                    pattern = "file:" + pattern;
                }
                if (pattern.startsWith("file:")) {
                    pattern = StringUtils.cleanPath(new File(pattern
                            .substring("file:".length())).getAbsolutePath()) + "/";
                }
                if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    logger.trace("Testing pattern: " + pattern
                            + " with property source: " + name);
                }
                if (normal.startsWith(pattern)
                        && !normal.substring(pattern.length()).contains("/")) {
                    matches = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Looks like by forcing 'normal' through the new `File(..).getAbsolutePath()` bit forces the slash to change from `/` to `\` (or `\\` some times), and thus is not matching against the patten variable (create at the next for loop).

In debug mode, I can see that pattern is set to `C: /Development/SVN/WSR_20150711/wsr-config/config/` while normal is set to `C:\\Development\\SVN\\WSR_20150711\\wsr-config\\config\\wsr\\wsr-dev.properties`.

Thoughts? Any chance we can fix this soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been fixed. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/150